# Gradle issue with sceneform - Program type already present: com.google.ar.schemas.lull

Tags: android, maven, gradle, 3d, augmented-reality

I am working on a project that will have a 3D model viewer in one fragment. In order to do so, I decided to use sceneform.

I downloaded sceneform plugin into Adnroid studio, downloaded and extracted sdk from Github, and I also copied libsceneform_runtime_schemas library into my project. I've added to my sceneform buil.gradle file line

```
implementation files("../libs/libsceneform_runtime_schemas.jar")
```

but that results in an error:

```
Program type already present: com.google.ar.schemas.lull.AabbDef
```

It is worth noticing that this is the first file in the jar under this path - which probably means that there will be more collisions.

If I'd try not to implement this library, then I get an error:

```
error: package com.google.ar.schemas.sceneform does not exist
```

I am using ar:core:1.17.0, and minSdkVersion 24 in sceneform gradle. 
I've cleaned and rebuilt the project, Invalidate Caches/Restart, and added multiDexEnabled- although I am not sure if I did it correctly. 
By using `gradlew sceneform:dependencies` I didn't find mentioned file.

I don't know how I can move forward, any help is much appreciated. If I can provide additional information, please let me know.

**Edit 1:** 
I've also tried to work with

```
implementation files("../libs/libsceneform_runtime_schemas.jar"){
   exclude ...
}
```

But I couldn't make it work. I wonder if that could be my solution.

Also, why does it try to implement this class since it already exists? Shouldn't there be some sort of check for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem by restoring my project from repo to the last moment before including sceneform, and I proceeded with all of the steps again; Gradle dependencies to the `libsceneform_runtime_schemas`, min java 8, min SDK version, copying scenformscr and sceneformux to my project again, and lastly - upgrading all classes to AndroidX.
After two days almost I couldn't remove the error, and I don't know what went wrong before, but this time it works like a charm.

TL;DR - I removed the sceneform from my project and imported it again.